# db_datawriter and db_ddladmin on a server-level?

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2017

Ok, since SQL Server 2016 we have new server-level permissions that allow to grant connect and select to/on any exising or future databases on the server instance

```
use master

grant connect any database to [Login]
grant select all user securables to [Login]
```

Tried to run below command:

```
grant insert all user securables to [Login]
```

But it throws an error

Is there any permission or role, or other method that grants permission to insert, update, delete (db_datawriter), or create objects inside user databases (db_ddladmin) on a server level - so it applies to all existing and future user databases ?
So DBA does not have to go in and update permissions whenever new database is added ?

Comment: Different role, same question/answer: [SQL server Read Only permission automatically for new databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205227/sql-server-read-only-permission-automatically-for-new-databases)

Comment: @LowlyDBA right, completely forgot about model db.. yes, that works

Comment: not sure though why wouldn't Microsoft add ability to "grant insert,update,delete [on] all user securables to [Login]" server-level permission